# Is it possible to debug Lambdas in Java 8

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, lambda, java-8

I just started playing with Java 8 Lambdas and I noticed that I can't debug them in the NetBeans IDE. If I try to attach a breakpoint to the following code I get a variable breakpoint which is definately not what I wanted:

```
private EventListener myListener (Event event) ->
{
  command1;
  command2; // Set Breakpoint here
  command3;
};
```

NetBeans attaches the debugger at the "myListener" variable but I can't step into the EventListener itself so I can't see what is happening inside it.

Is there debugging information missing, is this a missing feature in NetBeans or is it not at all possible to debug Lambdas in Java?

Comment: Just as confirmation, are you running with Netbeans 8? It might be that Netbeans 7.4 also supports Java 8.

Comment: Yes, I'm using NetBeans 8

Answer (score 5):

It works for me in Eclipse. For example:

```
public class Foo {

    private static final Runnable r1 = () -> {
        System.out.println("r1a");
        System.out.println("r1b");
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r2 = () -> {
            System.out.println("r2a");
            System.out.println("r2b");
        };

        r1.run();
        r2.run();
    }
}
```

I can add breakpoints to individual lines within both `r1` and `r2`, and they get hit appropriately, with stepping etc.

If I put a breakpoint on just the `run()` calls, I can step *into* the relevant lambda expression too.

So it sounds like all the debug information at least *can* be available.

EDIT: Apparently the above works in Netbeans too - I suggest you try it to check that *you* can get that working.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Did you set the breakpoint with strg+f8 or by clicking at the line number? It seems to work with strg+f8 but not with the line number so it's either a bug or my setup is broken...

Answer (score 3):

With the following sample code in **Netbeans 8 Release**:

```
private void init() {
    List<Map<Integer, String>> mapList = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<Integer, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put(1, "String1");
    mapList.add(map1);

    Map<Integer, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put(2, "String2");
    mapList.add(map2);

    Map<Integer, String> map3 = new HashMap<>();
    map3.put(1, "String3");
    mapList.add(map3);

    Map<Integer, String> map4 = new HashMap<>();
    map4.put(2, "String4");
    mapList.add(map4);

    Map<Integer, List<String>> response = mapList.stream()
            .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                            Map.Entry::getKey, 
                            Collectors.mapping(
                                    Map.Entry::getValue, 
                                    Collectors.toList()
                            )
                    )
            );
    response.forEach((i, l) -> {
        System.out.println("Integer: " + i + " / List: " + l);
    });
}
```

I can set a breakpoint on `System.out.println("Integer: " + i + " / List: " + l);` and inspect the values (`i`, `l`) perfectly fine.

So I'm inclined to say that it is working.

Comment: Works for me, thank you for the answer. But I have the same problem as with Jon Skeet's answer.

Answer (score 2):

In IntelliJ it also works for me:

```
Stream.generate(() -> {
    return random.nextInt();
}).limit(10).count();
```

I can debug into the return `random.nextInt()` but only when I provide a terminal operation like `count()`.

Comment: Just for your (and everyone elses) information, this code *could* be written as `new Random().ints(10)` to generate an `IntStream`, so total code could be `new Random().ints(10).count()`, I am aware though that then no lambda expression to capture would be present anymore.

Comment: Works for me, thank you for the answer. But I have the same problem as with Jon Skeet's answer.